# How to ask the user for confirmation in a client_action_multi in Odoo8?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have created an option in *More* button (in a tree view of `stock.move`), to apply some actions to the selected records. This is the code of my action:

```
<record id="stock_move_unrestricted_unlink_action" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Unrestricted unlink</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_stock_move"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
action = self.unrestricted_unlink(cr, user.id, context.get('active_ids', []), context=context)
    </field>
</record>
<record id="stock_move_unrestricted_unlink_option" model="ir.values">
    <field name="name">Unrestricted unlink</field>
    <field name="key2" eval="'client_action_multi'"/>
    <field name="model" eval="'stock.move'"/>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,%d'%stock_move_unrestricted_unlink_action"/>
</record>
```

It works great, but the problem is that I want to ask the user if he actually wants to apply those actions to the selected records. So I am looking for the functionality of the XML buttons attribute `confirm`.

```
<button name="my_button" type="object" string="Apply" confirm="Are you sure?"/>
```

But I was not able to fit that attribute in my case. How can I manage my purpose?

*Note: I'd rather not to call another wizard made by me which asks the question.*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your note about not wanting to use a wizard. My apologies.

Comment: Did you check implementation of discarding messages? You have to add a JS script, which will validate that - take a look at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/mail/static/src/js/mail.js#L372

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the functionality exists to have a confirmation before loading a window action. What you could do is have you window action open a wizard which only does one thing, provide two buttons ("Ok" or "Cancel"). If they execute the "Ok" function then execute your function otherwise don't.